# C#: how to round an Integer to the nearest 1000

Tags: c#, math, int, rounding

How can i round an (int) so that a number like (22536) is equal to 22000 or 23000?

I haven't found a specific method in the Math class, Math.Round seems to round double only to the nearest int.

Comment: Have you tried `yourInt / 1000 * 1000`?

Comment: The answer by Patrick Hofman is helpful, and it does not appear to be on the other question, so technically, this isn't a duplicate.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

By using modulus:

```
int x = 1500;

int result = x % 1000 >= 500 ? x + 1000 - x % 1000 : x - x % 1000;
```

It checks if `x` has any more than 499 when the thousands are stripped, and then rounds it.